# how solve mkdir and fopen file in php?

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite, mkdir, fclose

When I want to do folder for the member who registered into my site Inside this folder is a folder for photos and the main file of the member.
this is problem :-

The first folder is done with the member name successfully but the photo folder and the profile page of the member do not succeed.
                                                                thank you .....
this is my code I changed the code by the guy who helped me
 but the same problem exists
The first folder is successfully completed
The problem is in
file settings, folders, images, and index

```
<?php
$us = "";
 if(isset($_POST['username'])){ $us= $_POST['username']; }

 if(isset($_POST['username'])){
        mkdir("../profiles/$us", 0777, true);
        mkdir("../profiles/$us/images", 0777, true);
        $filename = "../profiles/$us/index.php";
        $ourFileName = $filename;
        $ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w');

        $written = "
        <html>
        <body>
        <?php
        echo \"hi man \";
        </body>
        </html>
        ";
        fwrite($ourFileHandle, $written);
        fclose($ourFileHandle);
        $myfile = fopen("../profiles/$us/setting.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
        $txt = "Minnie Mouse\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
        fclose($myfile);
```

}
?>

Comment: Turn on error reporting and start debugging from there. "Not working" isn't a very clear problem statement.

Comment: use php's error reporting; you have parse errors

Comment: i cant see any folder name of picture that you want to create? and are you creating php file to save data?

Answer (score 0):

You cant assign `$us = $_POST["username"]` inside of brackets and then use `$us`  again later.

Anything inside of brackets is constrainted within those brackets.

You have to define `$us = ""`  outside of the scope of the IF statement on your first   statement.

```
<?php
     $us = "";
     if(isset($_POST['username'])){ $us= $_POST['username']; }

     if(isset($_POST['username'])){

          etc etc
}
```

Comment: Thank you but the same problem exists
The first folder is successfully completed
The problem is in
file settings, folders, images, and index